# Migrating constructor function to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sails.js

So I've got a fairly large sails.js application and I'm planning to migrate the codebase to TypeScript over the next few months, I modified sails moduleloader to use ts-node (I will probably open a pull-request very soon) and that's all fine.

The issue is that I'm not very satisfied with the TypeScript that I'm coming up with and wanted to know if anybody had any suggestions.

In sails a hook looks something like this:

```
module.exports = function(sails) {
  return {
    initialize: function(next) {
      return next();
    }
  };
};
```

The TypeScript I initially came up with was

```
class Hook {
  constructor(public sails: any) {}

  initialize(next: Function) {
    return next();
  }
}

export = function(sails: any) {
  return new Hook(sails);
}
```

But I don't find the export function great and there is the problem that sails bind the scope and therefore this will cause some problems. The solution is to use the fat arrow but I'm not a big fan of the solution I came up with...

```
class Hook {
  constructor(public sails: any) {}

  initialize = (next: Function) => {
    return next();
  };
}

export = function(sails: any) {
  return new Hook(sails);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're exactly looking for, but if you don't want to go fully OOP with a `class Hook`, you can just as well settle for an `interface Hook`. That way, you can keep your original code and just add some types to it.

```
interface Hook {
  initialize(next: Function);
}

export = function(sails: any) : Hook {
  return {
    initialize: function(next) {
      return next();
    }
  }
}
```